# Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to apologize in advance if this has been answered. But I can not seem to find a solution that works for my problem.
I have been staring at my code for about 2 hours now and I can not seem to figure out why I am getting this error. Below is my PHP code. I am using a MYSQL DB that is hosted on a GoDaddy server.

```
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM location";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

I am getting my error at mysqli_close($result);

you can view via http://www.iqrleads.co/service.php  any help will be greatly appreciated my mind is drawing a blank

Comment: `mysqli_close()` is used to close DB connections, not result sets. See [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up procedural style mysqli and object orientated style. Try `while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){...}` instead

Comment: scrowler  - you are correct as I am building and iOS app that is pulling from MYSQL for a series of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

to

```
$con->close();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to stick with procedural? For consistency's sake.

Answer (score 2):

`$result` is not a mysqli connection object in your code.

You can remove `mysqli_close($result);` from your code, as it's not needed.

`mysqli_close($con);` should suffice for you.
You can also use `$con->close();` if you're so inclined.

See the reference for [mysqli_close](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)